# SSH to local ip in external network

Tags: networking, ssh, openssh

I know there is a lot of information about this subject but still I do not understand something.
We have internal wiifi network that include 4 desktops, each one has internal local ip address.
The router get external static ip addres .
I want to connect from my home laptop (different network) to each one of these desktop by their local ip users and passwords.
I understand how to create port forwarding from my router, but I want to keep it dynamic and connect by ssh to diferent desktop each time...
How can I do it?
There is any command similar to ssh username@local-ip external-ip ?

Answer (score 3):

You can specify port forwarding for incoming ports to forward to port 22 on each of the computers.

Say you have 4 computers on this network. We will call them A, B, C, and D. You have a laptop on a different network and you want to connect to computer A, B, C, or D.

Set incoming port forward on port 55555, for example, to forward to computer A on port 22.

To connect to computer A on port 22, you would connect to the external IP on port 55555 which will forward to computer A on port 22. The command to connect would read like so:

```
ssh username@externalIP:55555
```

example:

```
ssh holymoses@123.456.78:55555
```

Set up to forward all incoming connections on port 55556 to computer B, port 22 and so on and so forth.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed replay. Any way create connection without port forwarding?

Answer (score 0):

if you have 1 static ip then you can NAT that to a local.
you can ssh to that (ssh username@publicip) "public server" and from there you can jump to another local computer via ssh username@localip.

Comment: So should I connect to the external network, and then to the local ip address?